# Codeigniter 4 pagination on function in model

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, pagination, codeigniter-4

I'm currently stuck with the built-in pagination of CI4.
I try to paginate the results of a function in my model, which does not work:

My model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class CategoriesModel extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $allowedFields = [];
    protected $beforeInsert = ['beforeInsert'];
    protected $beforeUpdate = ['beforeUpdate'];

    //Kategorie(n) laden
    public function getCategories($categoryID = null)
    {
        $db = \Config\Database::connect();

        if (!$categoryID) {
            $builder = $db->table('categories');
            $query   = $builder->get();
            $results = $query->getResultArray();
        } else {
            $builder = $db->table('categories');
            $query   = $builder->where('categoryID', $categoryID);
            $query   = $builder->get();
            $results   = $query->getRow();
        }

        return $results;
    }
}
```

In my controller, i try to paginate the results of the "getCategories"-function from the model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\CategoriesModel;
use App\Models\PodcastsModel;

class Categories extends BaseController
{
    public function index($page = 1)
    {
        $this->request->setLocale(session()->get('locale'));

        //Helper laden
        helper(['form', 'template', 'userrights']);
        $data['template'] = getTemplate();

       
        $model = new CategoriesModel;

        $data['categories'] = $model->getCategories()->paginate(5, 'test', $page, 2);

        $data['pager'] = $model->pager;

        //Recht "13" (Benutzergruppen) prüfen
        if ($data['userrights'][13] == 0) {
            return redirect()->to('/admin');
        }

        //Views aufbauen
        echo view($data['template'] . '/templates/header', $data);
        echo view($data['template'] . '/backend/navigation');
        echo view($data['template'] . '/templates/sidebar');
        echo view($data['template'] . '/backend/categories');
        echo view($data['template'] . '/templates/footer');
    }
}
```

So the line

```
$data['categories'] = $model->getCategories()->paginate(5, 'test', $page, 2);
```

will cause the following error:

> Error
> Call to a member function paginate() on array

When i use

```
$data['categories'] = $model->paginate(5, 'test', $page, 2);
```

it works just fine. But it paginates ALL results from the categories table, as declared in the model.

But as i want to paginate the results from the function, depending on variables i pass to the model,

Is there a way to use the pagination class for model-functions?

Comment: Issue is with your return statement of $results. You are returning the final result (i.e an Array) because of this you can not chain the methods. Instead of results try to return the Object which can be chained. I usually use a Repository pattern, to chain the methods to achieve chaining rather than extending the Model and including the method in Model itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the paginate library correctly. It must be used at the end of your query builder instead of a `get()` for example.

Your model could return the paginate object.

```
public function getCategories($nb_paginate, $categoryID = null)
    {
        $db = \Config\Database::connect();

        if (!$categoryID) {
            $results = $this->paginate($nb_paginate);
        } else {
            $results = $this->where('categoryID', $categoryID)->paginate($nb_paginate);
        }

        return $results;
    }
```

And then catch it with your controller

```
$data['categories'] = $model->getCategories(5);
$data['pager'] = $model->pager;
```

You might want to give a look at the doc aswell : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this is "valid code" (i'm new to this formal CI4 models namespaces etc).  But this works fine for me.  Just make sure to filter your "search" in production properly for security

Controller:

```
$filter['search'] = $this->request->getGet('search');
$this->template->data['customers'] = $customer_model->get_customers_index($filter)->paginate(50);
$this->template->data['pager'] = $customer_model->pager;
```

Model:

```
function get_customers_index($filter)
{
    if (isset($filter['search']) and $filter['search'])
    {
      
        $this->like('id_number', $filter['search']);

    }
    return $this;
    
}
```